# Matlab 2017a -> 2018b. Access to .NET assembly different?

Tags: .net, matlab

Using Matlab 2017a I have written myself a wrapper to use vector CAN hardware. It's based on the `vxlapi_NET` from vector.

In the previous version I've been able to do like this:

```
xlstatus = obj.fid.XL_OpenDriver();
if xlstatus == vxlapi_NET.XL_Status.XL_SUCCESS   .....
```

because `xl_opendriver` returned something of type `vxlapi_NET.XL_Status` .
Makes complete sense...

Now with 2018b things appear to be completely different.
`XL_OpenDriver` returns something of type `XLDefine+XL_Status`.

Can anyone explain what this "plus" sign means here? I've never seen something like this before in Matlab. Furthermore I did not find any solution for translating `if xlstatus == vxlapi_NET.XL_Status.XL_SUCCESS` into something that is compatible with 2018b.

`vxlapi_NET.XLDefine+XL_Status.XL_STATUS` is not a valid expression, of course.

Is this a bug or why do things behave so different?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure? `XLDefine+XL_Status` is not a valid type name. And MATLAB is pretty good at backwards-compatibility. They usually have many versions that generate warnings before a function is removed, and they usually change a function name if they want to change its return values. Did you look through the release notes? This change must be mentioned there, with compatibility instructions.

Comment: Well I consider myself a poweruser. I fully agree: Never faced any backward compatibility issue. Thats why this is my first posting here and I'm really doubting myself. No Idea how to post a screenshot here but workspace shows: Name: xlstatus, Value: 1x1 XLDefine+XL_STATUS. Also if I look at the methods using libfunctionsview: "Plus"es everywhere. Probably it's the mingw that is broken? Installation is completely new.

Comment: xl_opendriver is part of the .NET wrapper that vector provides. Meanwhile I got a reply from Mathworks support. They confirmed that something changed: "The '+' in the name of the class or enumeration indicates that it is nested within another class. You cannot directly instantiate a nested class or enumeration from a .NET Assembly. In order to do so, you must use reflection. The interface has indeed change between the releases."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reply from MathWorks support. They confirmed that something changed:

> The '+' in the name of the class or enumeration indicates that it is nested within another class. You cannot directly instantiate a nested class or enumeration from a .NET Assembly. In order to do so, you must use reflection. The interface has indeed change between the releases.